# Php: How can one automate a script to change dates everyday?

Tags: php, cron, sftp

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$url      = '10.168.8.666';
// Make our connection
$connection = ssh2_connect($url);

// Authenticate
if (!ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password))
     {echo('Unable to connect.');}

// Create our SFTP resource
if (!$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection))
     {echo ('Unable to create SFTP connection.');}


$localDir  = 'file:///home/batman/Downloads/dbs';
$remoteDir = '/home/batbackup/Dropbox/dbs';
// download all the files
$files = scandir ('ssh2.sftp://' . $sftp . $remoteDir);
if (!empty($files)) {
  foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
        if (substr($file, 0, 11)=='07-Jun-2017'){
            # code...
              ssh2_scp_recv($connection, "$remoteDir/$file", "$localDir/$file");

        }

    }
  }
}
?>
```

I use this script to download backups from an sftp server everyday but i ve to manually change the date (**in bold**) in the script everyday. **Question**: is there a way i can make the script to change the date automatically so that i can set up a cron job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
date('d-M-Y')
```

It will become

```
#!/usr/bin/php

<?php
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$url      = '10.168.8.666';
// Make our connection
$connection = ssh2_connect($url);

// Authenticate
if (!ssh2_auth_password($connection, $username, $password))
     {echo('Unable to connect.');}

// Create our SFTP resource
if (!$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection))
     {echo ('Unable to create SFTP connection.');}


$localDir  = 'file:///home/batman/Downloads/dbs';
$remoteDir = '/home/batbackup/Dropbox/dbs';
// download all the files
$files = scandir ('ssh2.sftp://' . $sftp . $remoteDir);
if (!empty($files)) {
  foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {

        if (substr($file, 0, 11) == date('d-M-Y')) {
            # code...
              ssh2_scp_recv($connection, "$remoteDir/$file", "$localDir/$file");

        }

    }
  }
}
?>
```

If you want it to always be, let's say, yesterday, you may use it with `strtotime()`, so

```
date('d-M-Y', strtotime('yesterday'))
```

Comment: Do not answer duplicate questions, vote them as duplicate instead.

Comment: Sorry mate, you're right

Comment: thanks a million mate!!

Answer (score 2):

Replace your date with

```
date('d-M-Y')
```

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.date.php

This will take server current time.

Comment: Do not answer duplicate questions, vote them as duplicate instead.